# Toggle button and vertical grid splitter is not working simultaneously

Tags: wpf, togglebutton, gridsplitter

This is my sample code ,Please help me to achieve both goals simultaneously[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2mNy.png)
On click toggle button collapse and visible column and vertical split button.

In the below fig. First add toggle button and First column contain two column .
It contains second sub column is collapse or disable based on toggle button click.
and Spltter is working on outside two main column please help me as soon as possible

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
        <ColumnDefinition  />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>                
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Background="Green"
                Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid Grid.Column="1"
                  Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=toggleButton, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition  Width="300" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <WrapPanel Grid.Column="1"
                           Background="Aqua" />
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton"
                      Width="30"
                      Height="30"
                      Margin="0,10,10,0"
                      IsChecked="True"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </Grid>

    <GridSplitter Width="5"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  ResizeBehavior="CurrentAndNext" />
    <Grid Grid.Column="2"></Grid>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

From reading your question, I believe this is what you are trying to achieve. Please let me know if I didn't understand you properly.

```
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border
                Grid.Column="0"
                Background="Green">
                <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton"
                    Width="30"
                    Height="30"
                    Margin="0,10,10,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    IsChecked="True" />
            </Border>
            <Grid
                Grid.Column="1"
                MaxWidth="300"
                Visibility="{Binding ElementName=toggleButton, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                <WrapPanel Background="Aqua">
                    <TextBlock
                        Margin="8"
                        Text="Item 01" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Margin="8"
                        Text="Item 02" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Margin="8"
                        Text="Item 03" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Margin="8"
                        Text="Item 04" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Margin="8"
                        Text="Item 05" />
                </WrapPanel>
            </Grid>
            <GridSplitter
                Grid.Column="1"
                Width="5"
                Visibility="{Binding ElementName=toggleButton, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
            <Grid Grid.Column="3">
                <TextBlock
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Text="Column 2" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you @Keithernet. It is work for me as  my expectation.

Comment: @DamateNasir can you please mark my answer as the correct one?